# How to automatically reorder git commits?

Tags: git

I have next `git` history. As you can see I have two servers `amazon` and `origin`.

History on those servers is differ:

[image]

when I do `$git push amazon` I get error:

```
To amazon:/v1/repos/repo
 ! [rejected]          dash_v3 -> dash_v3 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'amazon:/v1/repos/repo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

The second `amazon` git server is my secondary server.

Is there any options that will allow me say:

It is OK/safe to reorder commits on `amazon` server and put `86ccb28a` before `93eeedeb` as it is on `origin` server?
And get next history as result:
[image]

**PS. I do not want to do `git push --force amazon`

Comment: Reordering commits *is* history change. No way you can push a changed history without `--force`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from IRC `#git` chat

kes you need to !rewrite history

> Rewriting public history is not recommended. Everyone who has pulled the old history will have to do work (and you'll have to tell them to), so it's infinitely better to just move on. If you must, you can use `git push --force-with-lease <remote> <branch>` to force (and the remote may reject that, anyway). See GIT [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase)